# Ubuntu SDK error running scope example

Tags: application-development, compiling, scopes

I'm learning to create a Scope for Ubuntu Touch with the Ubuntu SDK (installed from PPA) in Ubuntu 16.04.

I created a C++ Scope from template. When I'm trying to run I'm getting this error:

```
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ is not a full path to an existing compiler tool. Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

Please, how could I fix this? I have installed build-essential & g++ packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` is provided by the package `g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf`, the GNU C++ compiler for the armhf architecture. So just install it:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```